# AST Node for statements with Equality operator (==)

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Please let me know under which subclass of the ASTNode (org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode) the statements with the Equality operator (==) will come.

I need to find out the instances in code where comparison for Non primitive types (eg: Integer) is done using '==' operator. I want to ensure that the '==' operator is used only for primitive types (eg: int).

I have the ***Java code logic*** for performing this check (***using JDT library***), but not sure ***which type of ASTNode i have to visit*** in order to access such statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for 'InfixExpressions' where the 'operator' is == (or InfixExpression.Operator.EQUALS).

Note that you can simply use [ASTView](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php) to figure out answers to such questions yourself.

Comment: thanks deepak for the ASTView link. I will try the InfixExpression node and return back.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on you. How is your AST structured?

Generally, this is what I would do:

```
EqualityNode : Node 
{
  Node LHS;
  Node RHS;
}
```

As for ensuring syntactical correctness, that is someone doesn't do:

`if == else`

This should be checked by the parser before the node is added to the AST.

Comment: I am performing this operation on an already existing code base using java. I use JDT library to compile the class and then Visit the AST whcih is returned by the complied class. Not sure what you mean by  'checked by the parser before the node is added to the AST'. I have updated the question to clear any misunderstandings.